# How do I do a "combined" subscription model in iOS app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscriptions

We have a print magazine and we're going to release an app with subscription model, sort of kiosk app but with extended functionality.
Well, what we want is to solve the following cases:

Case 1 (complex)

- User buys a print issue and discovers a promo code in it. This code should allow user to download free digital copy of this issue from our app.
- User launches the app, opens a dialog box where he can enter the promo code.
- Voila! User gets his free digital copy of purchased print issue.
- Digital issue always remains in his list of purchased issues and is a valid purchased issue with all App Store options available for them (restore, etc.)

Case 2 (simple)

- User does not have a print issue. He launches the app and buys **the same** digital issue using IAP.

So, both issues  are the same (i.e. "blablabla magazine", November, 2014) but 1st was downloaded using a promo code, and 2nd was purchased with IAP, and they both should have the same properties and "weight" for App Store.

Problem is I don't know if this model will be approved by Apple. Or, if they do, how do I develop this? AFAIK, list of purchased and non-purchased items is provided by App Store and there's no way to intervene this process.
I didn't find any samples of using 3d party promo codes in iOS apps. Can anyone provide a solution for this, please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To keep a record of the promo code usage, I think the simpliest way to do it is to require an account. Once the user is logged with his account, you can tell a server that the promo code have been used with that account. If the user delete/reinstall your app, you will be able to restore all his promo codes from his account.

For your issue with IAP and promo codes, here is the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)
See the 11.16 section:

> Apps may enable additional approved features or functionality when
>   used in combination with specific approved physical products (such as
>   a toy) as long as the additional features and functionality are either
>   completely dependent on such hardware (for example an App that is used
>   to control a telescope) or also available through the App without the
>   physical products, such as by way of reward for achievement or by use
>   of IAP

So basically, what you want to do shouldn't be rejected.
But by experience when you do something that borderline with Apple's money (possibility to "undercut" IAP), you should expect a review failure, whatever the guidelines review says.

Keep in mind that the guidelines can be interpreted in your advantage, or in you disadvantage.

Comment: That Enter button... :)
Yes we're going to develop a backend which will support promocodes validation and storage. The major problem is to provide user a correct list of his purchased issues. The list should be provided by App Store backend just as it's been set up in iTunes Connect. It totally depends on user actual IAPs, and we can't send to App Store message that this user has purchased the issue because he actually has not.